# Can't create simple text slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to create simple slides for text and can't figure out why separate paragraphs start to show up. What i need is to change full div blocks with class text-block.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="text-blocks">
  <div class="text-block">
    <p>paragraph1</p>
    <p>paragraph2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-block">
    <p>paragraph3</p>
    <p>paragraph4</p>
    <p>paragraph5</p>
    <p>paragraph6</p>
    <p>paragraph7</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.text-block:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function(){
    $('#text-blocks :first-child').fadeOut()
      .next().fadeIn()
      .end()
      .appendTo('#text-blocks');
  },
  3000);
})
```

Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e2wFK/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change a selector to contain only direct children of `#text-blocks`

```
$('#text-blocks > :first-child').fadeOut()
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/e2wFK/2/)

Your previous selector `$('#text-blocks :first-child')` was selecting every first child inside `#text-blocks`, including the first paragraphs inside `.text-block` elements.